# Cross browser testing - same browsers differ on mac and pc?

Tags: cross-browser, cross-platform

For cross browser testing do I need to test the same versions of browsers on both Mac OS X and Windows?

For instance if a site works fine on Firefox 3.6 on Mac OS X, do I also need to check it on Windows with Firefox 3.6?

Comment: But Macs are PCs. Did you mean Mac OS X and Windows (and Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive never run into trouble by relying on testing it for only one os per browser,

Except that sometimes fonts may be missing depending on the os.

EDIT: Apparently fonts are an issue but there might be more, as explained [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/5759), so you might have to test cross-operating systems

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with Opera for mac messing up javascript on my site when I used @font-face but the PC version was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same browsers versions for different OS never give an issues unless and until you encounter with animated feature. Color would be a little variant. Also the images may appear stretched in MAC OS. Rest would be good to go !.